# Best Practices Way to Edit Magento Top-Links

Tags: php, xml, magento

Lets say we want to want to add a shopping cart icon right before the "My Cart" link on Magento's top links (see top links below).

What is the best way to do this?

Option 1. Do something to toplinks.php?

Option 2. Do something to links.phtml?

Option 3. An xml file?

Option 4. Any other options?

I understand that this can be done with CSS, but as my needs for customization grow, I want to know how this can be done without CSS so I am able to customize more difficult things.

[image]

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I posted it. I knew about the exchange but I assumed the question would get posted there automatically for some reason, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that there is a good answer to your question on [Magento.StackExchange] that's stated that you should use XML for that purpose[1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/best-practices-way-to-edit-magento-top-links)

And here is a very good article from Classy Lama on how to actually do that - [Editing Magento's Top Links (The Better Way)](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way)

Answer (score 0):

In page.xml

```
 <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

this is a template_links type block and it will render whatever you are going to throw at it.

in your custom xml with default node reference your block to that top.links and it will show up in the header.

Comment: If I have the following html to add an icon: <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> then how would I include it?